# How can I get all checkboxes which are unchecked?

Tags: c#, forms, checkbox

I am using checkedboxes separately (and not using a `CheckedListBox`). I would like to know what checkboxes in my form are (un)checked.

How can I also count the number of unchecked checkedboxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a `CheckedListBox`, you can simply call the property `CheckedItems`, which returns the items checked.

If you are using CheckBoxes separately, you can try to do something like this:

```
if(checkBox1.Checked)//checkBox1.Checked == true
    Console.WriteLine("CheckBox 1 is checked");

if(checkBox2.Checked)//checkBox2.Checked == true
    Console.WriteLine("CheckBox 2 is checked");
//continue to checking other CheckBoxes
```

You can also iterate through the `controls` in you form using a foreach loop. If you want to count the number of checked `CheckBoxes`, you can use a counter variable:

```
int checkedCheckBoxes = 0;//counter variable

foreach (Control c in this.Controls)//this is your form
{
    if (c.GetType() == typeof(CheckBox))//if the control is a CheckBox
        if (((CheckBox)c).Checked)//if it is a CheckBox and it's Checked
            ++checkedCheckBoxes;
}
```